# Prove that $\nu(mn) \le \nu(m)\nu(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\nu(mn) \le \nu(m)\nu(n)$

I think it is sufficient to prove this inequality for powers of prime numbers so that you can use the formula for $\nu$, but I'm not sure how the inequality is factored in

Comment: What is $\nu(m)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ and $m=p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k},$ where $\alpha_i,\beta_i\geqslant0$ for each $i.$ Then $\nu(mn)=(\alpha_1+\beta_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_k+\beta_k+1).$ On the other hand, $\nu(n)=(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_k+1)$ and $\nu(m)=(\beta_1+1)\cdots(\beta_k+1).$ Since $(\alpha_i+1)(\beta_i+1)=(\alpha_i+\beta_i+1)+\alpha_i\beta_i\geqslant\alpha_i+\beta_i+1$ for all $i$ then $\nu(mn)\leqslant\nu(m)\nu(n).$

Answer (score 1):

First show $\nu(p^\alpha p^\beta)\leq \nu(p^\alpha) \nu (p^\beta)$

This is clear, The left side is $\frac{p^{\alpha+\beta+1}-1}{p-1}$ and the right is $\frac{(p^{\alpha+1}-1)(p^{\beta+1}-1)}{(p-1)^2}$. So we must show $(p^{\alpha+\beta+1}-1)(p-1)\leq (p^{\alpha+1}-1)(p^{\beta+1}-1)$ Which is equivalent to $p^{\alpha+\beta+1}+p\geq p^{\alpha+1}+p^{\beta+1}$. Which is clear if we use Jensen as the function $f(x)=p^x$ is convex.

Since the function $\nu$ is multiplicative, suppose that $n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^s p_i^{\alpha_i}$ and $m=\prod \limits_{i=1}^s p_i^{\beta_i}$.

Then we have $\nu(nm)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^s \nu(p_i^{\alpha_i}p_i^{\beta_i})\leq \prod\limits_{i=1}^s\nu(p_i^{\alpha_i})\nu(p_i^{\beta_i})=\nu(n)\nu(m)$.

Comment: I would personally use the rearrangement inequality on $p^{\alpha+1}\cdot p^\beta +p\cdot1\geq p^{\alpha+1}\cdot1+p\cdot p^{\beta}$ (I think it's cooler than Jensen), but in the end, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's neater :)